# Pay for something in a period of time

Tags: prepositions, time

I write an essay and need to use the phrase like:

> He will pay for a laptop **in** ten years *(I suppose he borrowed
>   money, but I don’t want to use “pay back”)*

**Question**: should we use “in” preposition?

He will pay for a laptop in ten years. 
OR 
He will pay for a laptop ten years.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Vladkor, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: It'll take him ten years to pay off his laptop.  Or:  In ten years he'll have saved enough to buy a laptop.  It's unclear which you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express the duration of a payment plan, we would use the preposition *over*:

> [**over**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/over)  *prep*  (TFD Online)
>   8 a. Through the period or duration of: *records maintained over two years*.

So your sentence would work as follows:

> He will pay for a laptop **over** ten years.